# Solve the comparison

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, diophantine-equations

I have difficulties with these type of problems:

Solve the comparison: $\displaystyle67x + 17 \equiv 0\pmod{28}.$

I'm sure it is something very simple but I'm stuck on it more than $2$ hours :( .

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As $67\equiv11\pmod{28}$

$$67x+17\equiv0\pmod{28}\iff 11x+17\equiv0\iff11x\equiv-17\equiv11\pmod{28}$$

$$\iff x\equiv1\pmod{28}$$

Using property $\#12$ of [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Congruence.html) and as $(11,28)=1$

Comment: lol that was really fast. I get it. thank you :)

Comment: @MathError, My pleasure. Hope I could make the idea clear